# "MySQL C++ Connector Unresolved Dependencies (VS 2015)" solution did not work

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, cmake, mysql-connector

This refers to the original question posted by Tom Doodler, and answered by Norbert Boros, on the same topic. I am also trying to get the MySQL Connector/C or /C++ to work. Using MS Visual Studio 2017. Following the steps in the answer, did all the steps till :

Run this command ( assuming you want the STATIC DEBUG ):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_STATIC=true -DBUNDLE_DEPENDENCIES=ON -DSTATIC_MSVCRT=OFF -DWITH_JDBC=ON
```

The output on the screen says:

> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! in the last few lines. No "MYSQLCPPCONN.sln" either.

I have a pdf of the output but do not know how to attach it here. The output says three files are missing and one test failed, these are towards the end of the file, highlighted. Of course, their could be more problems that I could not identify, being a green thumb.

Any ideas about how to address this ?

I found ***Protobuf.sln*** at ***E:\MySQL*** C++ Connector Unresolved Dependencies (VS 2015) ***\mysql-connector-cpp-master\cdk\protobuf***. would this be of any use ?

Here is part of the output where problems occurred (there could be more problems elsewhere, have no idea. Also, had to format the output as "code", a posting requirement on the forum ?):

```
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
.
.
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR - Success
-- Check size of wchar_t
-- Check size of wchar_t - done
-- Looking for sys/endian.h
-- Looking for sys/endian.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h - not found
Wrote configuration header: E:/MySQL C++ Connector Unresolved Dependencies (VS 2
015)/mysql-connector-cpp-master/cdk/include/mysql/cdk/config.h
Legacy library soversion: 7
Looking for MySQL Client library:
CMake Error at jdbc/cmake/DepFindMySQL.cmake:128 (message):
Could not find MySQL headers at:
Point at MySQL client library location using WITH_MYSQL or
MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR, MYSQL_LIB_DIR settings.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
jdbc/cmake/DepFindMySQL.cmake:555 (main)
cdk/cmake/dependency.cmake:42 (include)
jdbc/CMakeLists.txt:147 (find_dependency)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: The **first error** you got is `CMake Error at jdbc/cmake/DepFindMySQL.cmake:128 (message):`. It tells `Could not find MySQL headers at:`. So the first clarification we need is whether do you have MySQL installed or not. If you have MySQL installed, then where do you have it installed or how have you installed it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev : MySQL 5.6.39 is installed at "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6". Installed using "mysql-installer-community-5.6.39.0.msi". Windows 8.1, 64-bit.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : Also, following your comment, took another look at the console output and found another error: "CMake Error at cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:86 (message):
Cannot find appropriate system libraries for SSL. Make sure you've
specified a supported SSL version. Consult the documentation for WITH_SSL
alternatives."

Comment: @Tsyvarev : Finally managed to create an EXE, but, on running the exe, it gives "System Error" message: "The program can't start because libmysql.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". Actually, this "libmysql.dll" was giving trouble and the program compiled after libmysql.dll was replaced with "libmysql.lib". If libmysql.dll is added, alone or with libmysql.lib, VC++ gives error: "LNK1107 - invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x320".

Comment: @Tsyvarev : When compiling with libmysql.dll, with or without libmysql.lib, the compiler ouput shows: 
'Try_DB_Con.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\_Documents\C++\Try_DB_Con\x64\Release\Try_DB_Con.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Try_DB_Con.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Try_DB_Con.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Try_DB_Con.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: Did you try adding this to your `cmake` command: `-DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR=/your/path/to/MySQL/include`? The error tells you to point to your MySQL installation using the `MYSQL_*` variables...